# How to avoid checkout options in opencart 2?

Tags: opencart

```
**Checkout**
Step 1: Checkout Options
Step 2: Billing Details   
Step 3: Delivery Details  -Not required : Want to move it
Step 4: Delivery Method   -Not required : Want to move it
Step 5: Payment Method 
Step 6: Confirm Order
```

How can I make the payment simpler by jumping straight step 1 to step 5? I don't need step 3 and 4!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the product's management page and change "requires shipping" from "yes" to "no". If all products in the basket have this setting, steps 3 and 4 will be skipped automatically.

If all products on your site are like this, you might want to also edit your language files, changing the numbering for the last two steps to 3 and 4 instead.

Comment: Yes, thnx for reply, but i'm asking in coding trems...so i can avoid this permanently...but working :)

Comment: Well, it's built-in, so no need to code anything really. I guess you could always edit the product admin template and make required shipping default to "no".